# passing copied texts as command line arguments to executable file

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, executable

How can I send text copied to the clipboard into an executable?
i tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "selectedText="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('clip') do set "selectedText=!selectedText!%%a"
a.exe !selectedText!
endlocal
```

but i got this:

```
INFO:
Type
CLIP /?
for
usage.
```